# curl not available by default, so what can my script use instead to GET/POST?

Tags: curl, wget, telnet

I am writing a Nautilus script that uses `curl` to GET/POST with a REST service.

Installing my script should be as simple as dropping a single file to ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts

My concern is that many computers might not have `curl` installed.
What would be a more widespread (should be installed by default on most distros) yet usable alternative to `curl`? Maybe `wget` or `telnet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the script is used under Linux (Nautilus), `wget` can be used in place of `curl`. Just change the command line arguments to the wget equivalents before running the script.

Comment: Is wget installed by default in most Linux distributions? (not just "available in the repos", really "installed by default")

Comment: In every system I've seen, GNU Wget is the default and cURL is occasionally installed as well. They both perform the same function, so it's really just a matter of picking one.

Comment: My bad, I had forgotten that I also need PUT, which wget can't do. Since it becomes a different question, I let this one and created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726572

Answer (score -2):

To make it more clear, distributors can make their decisions about what to install by default, so "installed by default in most Linux distros" doesn't make any sense.